# Regular expression: to find limited iterations

Tags: python, python-re

I need to find numbers in the given string and I need to extract first two numbers from the string. Ex., In second example I need to take `1536` and `678` but this code show the all the containg number.

```
import re
pattern = r"(\d{1,})"
match = re.findall(pattern, "123")
if match:
    print (match)
match = re.findall(pattern, "1536+678+ 888")
if match:
    print (match)    
match = re.match(pattern, "abc cde")
if match:
    print ("Match 3")
```

Comment: Just select up to the second object in the results: `print(match[:2])`

Answer (score 0):

Take the first two from matched results:

```
print(match[:2])
```